# How can I parse an integer out of a button's ID?

Tags: javascript, html, button, parseint

Let's say I have a bit of html that says:

```
<input type = "button" id = "start4" value="Start 4x4 Game" onClick="gameStart(this.id)"/>
```

And I want to change the action of the function in javascript based on the ID of the button, ideally by parsing out a 4 at the end of start4 through parseInt. I tried this, however, and could never get it to parse an integer value. I tested it by putting it into an alert button and it just spat out NaN at me. I'd really like to know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Please do not do that. Either directly replace `this.id` with a `4` or include `data-dimension="4"` so that you can easily retrieve the value.

Comment: I honestly can't believe I didn't think of simply using a number as a parameter. I guess I need to go back to remedial programming!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your IDs follow the same format of `start[number]` then in your gameStart function you can have it like this:

```
function gameStart(id) {
    var result = /[0-9]/.exec(id);
    if (result) {
        result = parseInt(result[0]);
    } else {
        return false;
    }

    ...
}
```

Then you can use `result` in your `gameStart` function. In this case it will be `4`.

Code breakdown:

`var result = /[0-9]/.exec(id);` assigns `result` to a Regex search for numbers in your string (which is `start4`).

`if (result) {` checks if the Regex search actually found a number, if so, move on, if not, abort the function.

`result = parseInt(result[0]);` The Regex search returns an array of results, the first element in the array being the actual found string. So we assign `result` to the first element in the array, and then apply `parseInt()` to convert that string to a number.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to store such thing in `data` attribute. However you can parse id via regex to get last number.

`var number = parseInt(this.id.match(/\d+$/)[0])`

Make sure to check match[0] is not undefined.